# Is there another simple way to make isGrounded work on Unity 5?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been programming like an hour or so, then i realice that in unity 5 the charactercontroller.isGrounded doesn't work. Could anyone give me a answer?
This is the code i had

```
public float playerSpeed = 3f;
public float realSpeed = 3f;
public float jumpSpeed= 7f;
public float sprintSpeed= 5f;
public float gravity = 20f;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    CharacterController CC = GetComponent<CharacterController>();




    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)){
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * playerSpeed* Time.deltaTime);

    }
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)){
        transform.Translate(Vector3.back * playerSpeed* Time.deltaTime);
    }
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)){
        transform.Translate(Vector3.right * playerSpeed* Time.deltaTime);
    }
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)){
        transform.Translate(Vector3.left * playerSpeed* Time.deltaTime);
    }
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && CC.isGrounded){
        transform.Translate(Vector3.up * jumpSpeed* Time.deltaTime);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift)) {
        playerSpeed = sprintSpeed;
    } else {
        playerSpeed = realSpeed;
    }

}
```

}`

Comment: Explain "doesn't work?" Is this something documented that you've found, or just your experience? If the latter, it could be something specific to your project...

Answer (score 0):

So you're trying to make your character jump but only when it's on the ground?

I had this problem before a well. My solution was to make an empty gameobject and place it as a child of your character and a little bit and then put a collider as a trigger on your empty object.

Then you can have collision detection on your empty object to detect whether it is ontriggerstay on just the bottom side. It also compensates for little bumps and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code you are not using any character controller. You are just changing the position of Object by using translate which will never collide with your ground. Where as to use character controller you have to provide a move direction with gravity to character controller so that its will use character controller to move your player. Gravity vector will pull your character downward and collide with ground then isGrounded will be true. Check [Character Controller](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.Move.html) implementation in this unity script reference for detail.